# JQuery Document Ready AJAX function - image not loading until page refreshed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have this custom code, taking an XML file and using the values to populate certain data on my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'config.xml?date=' + moment().format('hhmmss'),
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
            var Img = 'images/' + $(xml).find('sitelogo').text();
            $('#logo').append('<img src="' + Img + '" />');
            var Height = $('#logo').height() / 2;
            var Width = $('#logo').width() / 2;
            $('#logo > img').css('height', Height);
            $('#logo > img').css('width', Width);
            $('#header').css('height', Height + 20);
            $('#sitename').text($(xml).find('sitename').text() + ' Visitor Log');
        }
    });
});
```

My issue is that everything works fine EXCEPT for the image (`$('#logo').append('<img src="'+Img+'" />');`) which doesn't show on the first page load (when checking the console the image *has* loaded but hasn't shown up until you perform a page refresh.  Everything else works as expected but I just can't figure out what's going on.  I've had a Google and found lots of results regarding JQuery Turbolinks, but this is the first I've heard of it and I'm certainly not using it.  Nothing specifically solves my issue from what I've read.

Comment: can you share your code on 'fiddle' or `codepen`

Comment: Could you check in the console that the image element is actually visible after the image has loaded? I mean, that it has a width and a height, etc.

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle or a url to the page

Comment: Glad it helped  @Hyperjase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and verified this problem in Chrome.

The issue is, when you load the script first, the image is appending but the the Height is `0px` (because the default height of empty `div` is `0px` ).

Then when you refresh, browser compute and add the height

[image]

Which means when you perform `$('#logo').height() / 2;` , it actually calculated as `0/2`

In refreshing, it is computed by browser as follows.

[image]

To overcome this, add a `height` to the div as

```
<div id="sitelogo" style="height:400px;"></div>
```

Then it will be shown on first load as follows

[image]

#### Note

The default width of a `div` is `100%` of it's container.

The default height of an empty `div` is `0px`.

Comment: This solves part of the problem, adding `height: 120px` into my CSS ensures the DIV is the correct height, but on first load - the image still isn't showing.  I can't show you the site this is on as it's an intranet, but I will try to sort a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: do one thing. press f12, click on the image with id `sitelogo`, check `img` is present or not. if yes, hover on it and check the dia as shown in the screenshots above

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sagar V for the answer - I had to assign BOTH width and height to the `#logo` DIV - the image was there, it was just invisible within a 0 x 0 container.  I think by trying to be smart, I made my life harder and this is the result.  This will be a valuable lesson in keeping things simple!